# Online Service That Duplicates another Data from another Online Backup?

Tags: dropbox, synchronization, online-storage, online-backup

Having all information backed up in one place in the cloud is risky since should anything happen with that place, your data will be gone. I use only Dropbox and i am risking it. I could also use Box to store that same data or other online service, but the problem is reuploading same data again and again since my upload is 26KBps and i am not going to wait weeks for this.

Is there such service that pulls copies of backed up data to its servers/several servers to store a backup there without making me to reupload data? Or better yet, is there such service that can duplicate my data stored in Dropbox to other backup services like Box, SkyDrive, iDrive, Mozy etc.?

Comment: Not sure that's possible... It would kinda be against their interest to enable people to move directly from their service to another. Sadly, it's always about locking the customer in.

Comment: Often online backup services replicate the data to multiple data centers. Is that enough, or do you also want to have multiple companies in case one of them falls down?

Comment: Hmmm i don't know. Well it is best of course to diversify between companies. Like ZOHO can pull emails from Hotmail and Gmail, if it was with data storage services, would be nice. But it would be better to have one distribution service pulling datafrom one source and distributing to multiple sources (companies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [cloudHQ](https://www.cloudhq.net/dropbox) that make syncing between Dropbox, Basecamp, and Google Docs possible. In that way it can also act as a backup I guess.